# Cast via reflection and use of Class.cast()

Tags: java, reflection, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Java Class.cast() vs. cast operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555326/java-class-cast-vs-cast-operator)

I am unsuccessfully trying to find out what `Class.cast()` does or what it may be good for. At the same time I am wondering whether I can somehow cast an object via reflection.

First I thought something like the lines below might work:

```
Object o = "A string";
String str = Class.forName("java.lang.String").cast(object);
```

But without an explicit cast it does not work.

So what is the `cast` method of `Class` class good for? And is it somehow possible just with reflection to cast objects, so you find the object's class, use `Class.forName` on it and cast it somehow?

Comment: There is a good explanation: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstance][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstance

Answer (score 39, accepted):

An example where is does work:

```
class Favorites {
    private Map<Class<?>, Object> map = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

    public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(map.get(clazz));
    }

    public <T> void put(Class<T> clazz, T favorite) {
        map.put(clazz, favorite);
    }
}
```

which allows you to write:

```
Favorites favs = new Favorites();
favs.put(String.class, "Hello");
String favoriteString = favs.get(String.class);
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that Class.forName() returns a `Class<?>`, i.e. a class object representing an unknown type. While the compiler could possibly infer the type in your example, it can not in general. Consider:

```
Class.forName(new BufferedReader(System.in).readLine())
```

what's the type of this expression? Clearly the compiler cannot know what the class name will be at runtime, so it doesn't know whether

```
String s = Class.forName(new BufferedReader(System.in).readLine()).cast(o);
```

is safe. Therefore it requests an explicit cast.

Answer (score 5):

The return type of `Class.forName` will be `Class<? extends Object>`. You want `Class<? extends String>`, for instance using `String.class`.

```
String str = String.class.cast(object);
```

Not very useful, until you start replacing `String` with some kind of interface type.

In any case, reflection is generally evil.

Comment: Without reflection, none of us would still be discussing Java 17 years after it was invented.

Comment: @staffman Well, I would certainly have a smaller job. (Oh, and 17 years after fcs. (Which didn't have reflection.))

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid a warning e.g. with the following code:

```
public <T> T getObject(Class<T> type){
  Object o = getSomeObject();
  if (type.isInstance(o)){
     return type.cast(o);
  } else {
     return null;
  }
}
```

while the following code will raise a warning:

```
public <T> T getObject(){
  return (T) getSomeObject();
}
```

Comment: Could someone put an example of the use of the first getObject method? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`Class.forName` will return a `Class<?>` type object. The `cast` method will return the type parameter of Class. Thus, in this case it'll return a ? (Object) type object.

You should try:

```
Class<String> strClass = (Class<String>) Class.forName("java.lang.String");
String str = strClass.cast(object);
```

See also [Class.cast()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: `Class<? extends String> strClass = String.class.asSubclass(Class.forName("java.lang.String"));`

Comment: That is nice, wasn't aware of it.

Comment: what if the return type of Class.cast(object) is also a class which should be reflected, how do i cast the object to it ?