# How to cast to a specified class type?

Tags: java, spring, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cast via reflection and use of Class.cast()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918550/cast-via-reflection-and-use-of-class-cast)

I have a question related to java programming. I want to have the ability to choose the casting type through a string parameter passed to the function. As you see there is a main class which have to be casted to a sub type. These subtype should be specified by the user. How we can do that ?

```
public void casting(String subClassCast)
 {
      MainClass mainClass = (subClassCast) MainClassFactory.get();
 }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you don't know at compile time what to cast to, then there's no reason to do a cast.

Answer (score 2):

The cast as you write it does nothing.

The cast serves for assigning an object of a superclass to a subclass reference

```
Object obj = a.toString();
String str = (String) obj;  // The compiler can't check that at runtime obj will be
                            // a String, so the programmer "forces" the compiler to
                            // allow the assignation
```

needs a cast, but in

```
Object obj2 = (String) obj;
```

the cast does nothing (other than throwing a `ClassCastException` if `obj` is not a String).

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
MainClass mainClass = Class.forName(subClassCast).cast(MainClassFactory.get());
```

But I'm not sure it is a good idea.