# Can I make class cast in Java using methods?

Tags: java, casting

So I do not like this for some reason:

```
((Foo) list.get(0)).getBar();
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
list.get(0).castTo(Foo.class).getBar();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not like the first (other than the problem that the precedence is always making you wonder about adding extra `()`)?

Comment: @HotLicks I think it breaks the view and slows down typing a lot.

Comment: There is no dynamic cast mechanism, if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: Yeah, the cast syntax inherited from C sucks for several reasons.  But it's far from the only wart on the language.

Comment: @HotLicks I am a beginner so this kind of caught my eye. The others I would not know really.

Comment: May not be applicable for a broader context, but at least in this example you can avoid casting by generics

Comment: Just consider it a minor wart.  It's that way for historical reasons, and it's not going to change, so we live with it.  Just be thankful you're not dealing with C strings and arrays.

Comment: Do understand that if you use one of the suggested "alternatives" then others (including your instructor) will have trouble reading your code and will consider it to have non-standard "standards".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `class.cast(Object)`.
Read [Java Class.cast() vs. cast operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1555387/3453226).

```
Foo.class.cast(list.get(0)).getBar();
```

However, I suggest you to use a **variable**.

```
Foo foo = (Foo)list.get(0);
Bar bar = foo.getBar();
```

Comment: Just because you **can** use it doesn't mean you **should**.

Answer (score 3):

You do have `Class.cast(Object obj);` method. But it would be stupid to use instead of the regular way just because you don't happen to like it.

It's also an extra method call instead of a compile-time construct, so they're not directly equivalent to each other.

Not to mention that `6ton` already mentioned in the comments that the example is avoidable with generics...

Comment: What is the reasonable reason to use it?

Comment: When you're working with a lot of reflection and generics. So quite rarely.