# Java - Typecast a object to a String Class Named Object

Tags: java, android

I have a object of a class. I want to typecast it to another class.
So, what we generally do is -

```
HeavyVehicle hv = new HeavyVehicle();
Truck tr = (Truck) hv;
```

if we typecast the **hv** object to **truck** classes object.

But if the name of the class is stored in a string like this-

```
String ToCastStringName = "Truck";
```

Is there any way to typecast the **hv** object to a class named **ToCastStringName**?

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times. Instead, use the edit button to update your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your use case is but you can actually use:

```
Class.forName(className).cast(someObject)
```

to dynamically cast an object knowing only the class name. In your case, the code:

```
HeavyVehicle hv = new HeavyVehicle();
String ToCastStringName = "Truck";
Class.forName(ToCastStringName).cast(hv);
```

would return an object of the type `Truck`.

There's a long discussion about uses and tradeoffs of either approach in this post: [Java Class.cast() vs. cast operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555326/java-class-cast-vs-cast-operator)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Class.forName(ToCastStringName).cast(hv)` provided ToCastStringName is a fully qualified name of class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using Class.forName() is a lot more complicated in android (than indicated by the Java solutions).  I've tried to follow several "java" examples, and have  yet to get anything that didn't result in a ClassNotFound error in Andriod Studio.

Android is its own separate language, and some things just working differently here.  I searched, and it appears the answer is a lot more complicated in Android. It apparently has to do with how their packed into APKs.  As you can see from this post, the solution is quite involved.

```
http://yenliangl.blogspot.com/2009/11/dynamic-loading-of-classes-in-your.html
```